# Tridion User Interface 2012 - 401 unauthorized

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I'm working on setting up Tridion User Interface 2012 and have hit a problem.

I'm pretty sure I must have missed a step in the installation, but can't figure out what.

I've created a very simple Page Template inside a test website publication, with just one component presentation on it.

When I view the source of my published page I can see the JSON and JS I would expect, eg

```
<!-- Start Component Presentation: {"ComponentID" : "tcm:24-5001", "ComponentModified" : "2011-12-07T09:34:48", "ComponentTemplateID" : "tcm:24-294-32", "ComponentTemplateModified" : "2012-07-23T06:11:14", "IsRepositoryPublished" : false } -->
<h1><span><!-- Start Component Field: {"XPath":"tcm:Content/custom:Content/custom:title[1]"} -->Artwork</span></h1>
```

and also further down the page just before the closing `</body>` tag:

```
<!-- Page Settings: {"PageID":"tcm:24-9412-64","PageModified":"2012-07-23T07:16:30","PageTemplateID":"tcm:24-9411-128","PageTemplateModified":"2012-07-23T07:13:12"} -->
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" defer="defer" src="http://<cme-hostname>/WebUI/Editors/SiteEdit/Views/Bootstrap/Bootstrap.aspx?mode=js" id="tridion.siteedit"></script>
```

Where `<cme-hostname>` is my CMS address.

Using Chrome developer tools, I can see when the following url is requested I am getting a 401 unauthorized error.

```
http://<cme-hostname>/WebUI/Editors/SiteEdit/Views/Bootstrap/Bootstrap.aspx?mode=js
```

Does anyone have any idea what I might be doing wrong? (Tridion 2011 SP1-1)

Comment: What do you get when you try to load that URL yourself? 401 unauthorized should be OK, as long as it's followed by a prompt to login to Tridion...

Comment: Hi Nuno, thanks for getting back to me. When I try that i just get an empty response - again looking at the Chrome developer tools i see the 401 unauthorized

Comment: OK, then there must be something going on with your browser, 401 should ask you to authenticate. Can you try with a different browser?

Comment: Hi Nuno, Thanks for you help with this - i figured it out with both yours and Barts help - see the comments on Barts answer for the solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A 401 unauthorized message could indicate incorrect authentication setting in IIS. You should change the “View” folder (WebUI\Editors\SiteEdit\Views) from Anonymous to Windows Authentication as displayed in the example image below.
[image: UI 2012 authentication settings]

Comment: Hi Bart, thanks for getting back to me. i've just been and checked this and the settings are as per your screenshot.

Comment: So a combination of yours and Nunos answers helped me figure it out - Requests to http://<cme-hostname>/ were getting challenged to authenticate just fine - it was just requests to the bootstrap folder that were not. Somehow although the WebUI, Editors, SiteEdit and Views folder all had windows authentication switched on, the Bootstrap folder did not. Thank-you for your help!